# Create an unusual bar chart in PowerBI/DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to create a bar chart, axis - territories measure - sales amount The "trick" is, I'd like to add two more bars to the chart - Global and Local. I've got them already distinguished in the data model. It will look like on

[image]

**Its not my requirement. believe me I will never want to do that, just two separate charts. Why i got minuses?**

Comment: After Power BI gave us this nice grouping feature, there are always people who want to see old and new side by side because otherwise they wouldn't really understand what's going on. Unfortunately not very "unusual".

Comment: Its not my requirement :( believe me I will never want to do that, just two separate charts. So its kind of tricky/difficult? Why i got minuses?

Comment: Maybe because there's no sample data and the question isn't [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (nor reasonable).

Comment: I suspect you have minuses because generally images are not accepted in questions (yours appears to already be broken), you haven't tried to explain what you have already tried, and there is no reproduceable example. These are just a few that spring to mind. FYI i have not downvoted this question.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Will keep that in mind. Though the picture tells more than words especially if one talks about viz

Answer (score 1):

At first, create two more tables: one with unique *Group* names (*dict_Table* in my example below) and one with dictionary structure (*Table (2)* in my example).
Don't forget to create a relation in **Data model** view, like this (pay attention to bi-directional relation between *dict_Table* and *Table (2)*):
[image]
The *dict_Table* is necessary here because you need unique values in related fields to do this trick. Such relation between *Table* and *Table (2)* is impossible for most cases.

To get a desired result you should add *Macro Group* to **Axis**. Then write two different measures (*Sales amount* and *Sales Amount LY*) and add them to **Values**.

With my dummy data:

**Table:**

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| A | 20 |
| B | 15 |
| B | 25 |

**Table (2):**

| Group | Macro Group |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
| B | B |
| A | Global |
| B | Global |

**dict_Table:**

| Group |
| --- |
| A |
| B |

and measures:

```
Group Sum = 
SUM('Table'[Value])

Group Average = 
AVERAGE('Table'[Value])
```

the result looks like:
[image]